# Using ClassLoader.getSystemResource to get file path in JAVA

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm writing a dynamic web module using Tomcat 7 with Eclipse and Java 8, and my problem is that a required JAVA project on the build path is using the following to load files (lexicons, dictionaries, etc):

```
String filePath = "conf/test.txt"; // my test file is in WEB-INF/conf
String absolutePath = ClassLoader.getSystemResource(filePath).getPath();
```

I'm getting a null pointer so it's not finding the file.

When using the following, it finds the file:

```
String absolutePath = new File(filePath).getAbsolutePath();
```

**The problem is**:

I am required to use `ClassLoader.getSystemResource`. How can I specify my file's path for it to work without getting a null pointer (without using absolute paths too)?

Comment: Why do you specifically need to use #getsystemResource() ?

Comment: Because I am using several projects written by other developers on my build paths and they all load files that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem you have is that `SystemClassLoader` used to start the program, so given you are trying to search for a resource in a web container such as tomcat, this will NOT work.

If I were you, I would just use the following,

```
this.getClass().getResource(“/top.txt”)
```

Comment: If you are using getClass from a static method, you will get an error, then just use TheClassName.class instead of getClass(). Thanks to @Ducaz035

Answer (score -2):

Use below please...

String tempPath = new File("").getAbsolutePath();

String filePath=tempPath+"conf/test.txt";

use ClassLoader.getResource() and below is explanation...

ClassLoader::getSystemResource() uses the system classloader. This uses the classpath that was used to start the program. If you are in a web container such as tomcat, this will NOT pick up resources from your WAR file.

Class<T>.getResource() prepends the package name of the class to the resource name, and then delegates to its classloader. If your resources are stored in a package hierarchy that mirrors your classes, use this method.

ClassLoader.getResource() delegates to its parent classloader. This will eventually search for the resource all the way upto the system classloader.

Comment: The question is how to specifically use ClassLoader.getSystemResource to find my file.